# How could I use tesseract on video streamed to QuickTime from iOS device?

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract, quicktime

I want to perform OCR, using tesseract, on the video coming from my iOS device. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtSGSXKggEo) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtSGSXKggEo) gets me part of the way there by using a primary camera as the source, I just need to know how to use the QuickTime video as a source